# MySQL query (sum) not working in VB

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, mysql-workbench

I want to add the ages of all the employees in MySQL database column(using sum query) and then want to display its result(the value)on the click of a button in VB in a textbox.I have given a try but its not working.I am not able to figure this out.Please help....[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IguiN.png)

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

Dim Mysqlconn As New MySqlConnection

Mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;port=85;password=andy1234;database=data"



Try
    Mysqlconn.Open()
    command.Connection = Mysqlconn

    command.CommandText = "select sum(age) from data.etable"

    Dim sqlresult As Object
    sqlresult = command.ExecuteScalar

    Dim str As String
    str = sqlresult
    TextBox5.Text = str

    Mysqlconn.Close()

Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Mysqlconn.Dispose()

End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: what error? Are you even connected on port 85?

Comment: @Drew .... yes it is connected to MySQL server(I changed the port). Yes I got an error saying " NullReference  Exception was Unhandled"(in form of a dialogue box) indicating my connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a demo on standard port 3306 for Mysql

### Schema

```
create table etable
(   eid int auto_increment primary key,
    age int not null
);

insert etable(age) values (1),(2),(3);
```

### VB Code

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection

    Public Sub connect()
        ' Perform a connection test, and save ConnectionString
        ' in Module-level variable "conn"

        Dim dbname As String = "dbname"
        Dim hostname As String = "hostname"
        Dim user As String = "dbuser"
        Dim password As String = "password"
        If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
        conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}", hostname, user, password, dbname)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("Connection Test Successful")
            ' and ConnectionString set for subsequent queries
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        conn.Close() ' close connection for now
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        connect()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim iAgeSum As Integer
        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(String.Format("select sum(age) as ageSum from etable"), conn)
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        If result Is Nothing Then
            TextBox1.Text = "junk"
        Else
            iAgeSum = Convert.ToInt32(result.ToString()) ' for the purpose of showing conversion
            TextBox1.Text = iAgeSum
        End If

        conn.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

### Screenshot

[image]